# regular expression capturing group

Tags: regex

I have a very simple question on regular expressions:

Source string:
Name:`Bob Age:20`

Pattern 1:`[\d]+`

Pattern2: `([\d])+`

Why is it that pattern 1 matches: `"20"` while pattern 2 matches just `"0"` ?

I know that the quantifier + is greedy, so it matches one or more, but why is that when i surround the character class by parenthesis , it only matches the last character ?

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: Get the `group 0` in the 2nd pattern, and you would get `20` for it too.

Comment: using python's built in module "re"

Comment: With python, use `m.group()` to get `20`.

Comment: Note that there's no reason to use `[\d]` : simply use `\d`.

Answer (score 2):

It matches both. The global match is the number, but the captured match is what's between parenthesis, that is `[\d]` (which is `\d`).

The exact behavior will depend on the function/language you're using : you might get "20" (the global match) or "0" (the captured group). If you want to capture all the digits, use `(\d+)` (the + inside the group).

Answer (score 1):

Pattern 1: `[\d]+` matches a sequence of decimals (zero or more), can also be written `\d+` and will match `20`.

Pattern2: `([\d])+` matches captures (zero or more) of a group containing `only one` decimal, so it will match `2` and `0`.

*In addition* :

Pattern3: `([\d]+)+` matches captures (zero or more) of a group containing `one or more` decimals in a `greedy` way, it will match `20`.

Pattern4: `([\d]+?)+` matches captures (zero or more) of a group containing `one or more` decimals in a `lazy` way, it will match `2` and `0`.